# All my pendrives in read only mode

Tags: usb, usb-drive, read-only

I upgraded one of my computers to Ubuntu 17. I wanted to copy some files in a pendrive from that computer to my personal notebook, and I had a problem because Ubuntu said that the pendrive was in read only mode. I plkugged and unplugged, I formatted it again in FAT and NTFS, but nothing changed. I also executed chownand tryed all the solutions in:
[USB devices showing a read only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563764/usb-devices-showing-a-read-only)

But it is telling me the same. I am desperate, I really need to copy some heavy files soon and I don't have Windows to properly format the pendrive. 
Now it is not working properly in other computers...

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Who owns the drive? If you use nautilus to open the drive, right click, and select properties -> permissions, who shows as owner

Comment: @brndn2k it says "moi" (me). There are two combos and I can change the 'group' and 'others' permissions to 'read and write', but if I close such window those options go back to 'just read'

Comment: There are tips in the following links, https://askubuntu.com/questions/886701/how-do-i-get-permission-to-edit-in-my-usb/886735#886735  , https://askubuntu.com/questions/895733/copying-files-to-a-usb-drive/895782#895782 , https://askubuntu.com/questions/881536/cannot-format-usb-flash-drive-after-creating-ubuntu-installation-disk/881551#881551